# WPF controls in StackPanels not getting scroll bar

Tags: wpf, window, scrollbar, stackpanel

I have the following window setup:

```
<Window x:Class="SearchWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POR"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="SearchWindow"
    Height="450" 
    Width="1000"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    Icon="/Images/receipt.ico" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- Search Box -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="SP_SearchBox" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border CornerRadius="6"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Padding="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="\Images\magnify.png" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TB_search"    
                                 Width="220"  
                                 FontSize="12"    
                                 BorderThickness="0"  
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="left"    
                                 Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                 Text="Search..."
                                 Background="Transparent"    
                                 Foreground="Gray"    
                                 TextChanged="TB_Search_TextChanged"
                                 PreviewKeyUp="TB_search_PreviewKeyUp"/>
                    <Image x:Name="BTN_Clear" Source="\Images\close.png" Height="20" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" Cursor="Hand" 
                               MouseLeftButtonUp="BTN_Clear_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- Auto Suggestion box -->
        <Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SP_SearchBox}"
                   AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide" Width="263" HorizontalOffset="-2" VerticalOffset="-2">
            <Border CornerRadius="6"
                    BorderBrush="Gray"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Padding="1">
                <ListView x:Name="LV_hints" Visibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0"
                         SelectionChanged="LV_hints_SelectionChanged"/>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
        <!-- Grid 1 -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <DataGrid x:Name="DG_Orders" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      Margin="6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button  Click="BTN_ShowItems_Click"
                                            Margin="3">Show Items</Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <!-- Grid 2 -->
            <DataGrid x:Name="DG_OrderItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      Margin="6" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="BTN_Receipt" Click="BTN_Receipt_Click"
                                            Margin="3">Receipt</Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I cannot figure out why am I not getting a scroll bar when the bottom `DataGrid` has more data and appears off the window at the bottom of it.

I've tried using `<DockPanel>` in various places, like the top-most `<StackPanel>` but that still did not show me any scroll bars. I have read that using controls such as `<DockPanel>` or `<StackPanel>` should automatically give me a scrollbar when the content does not fit on the window, but in my case it just goes off screen.

I have also tried using `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` and `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` and having a row and a column on the sides as well as top and bottom for 5px margin for the content, but again, the bottom `DataGrid` just expands down and cuts off on the window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have read that using controls such as <DockPanel> or <StackPanel> should automatically give me a scrollbar when the content does not fit on the window" - that is wrong. scrollbars are provided by ScrollViewer. in fact, if you want vertical scrollbars to appear, get rid of all vertical StackPanels - they consider Height infinite and therefore condition for enabling vertical scrollbar doen't activate

Comment: "Also, minor issue" - one question per post, please.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood the statement then about the `<DockPanel>` or `<StackPanel>`. If I remove all my Stack Panels should I revert to using Column and Row Definitions to correctly line up my controls as if they were in a StackPanel?

Comment: Also, removed the minor question - apologies.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the Grid  with `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman As odd as it sounds, I've gone through so many posts on scrollbars and never noticed there is a `<ScrollViewer>` as I tried `<ScrollBar>` and that didn't work... Bad day for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` needs a height constraint otherwise it will stretch to infinite. If the layout is defined correctly, the `DataGrid` will provide its own `ScrollViewer` (same applies to other ItemsControl classes like `ListBox` and `ListView`).
Panels in general, like `Grid`, `DockPanel`, `Canvas` or `StackPanel`, don't have their own `ScrollViewer`. They need to be hosted by a `ScrollViewer` explicitly.

You can define this constraint either by hosting it inside a `Grid` or by explicitly setting the `Height` property.

For complex layout arrangements and advanced resize behavior, you should always prefer to use a `Grid` as root panel. At least you should know the different resize behavior. In your case, the `StackPanel` is not the proper root panel to layout the page.

The following example creates a similar layout by utilizing the `Grid` as a content host. Instead of a vertically oriented `StackPanel` it uses a `Grid` that defines rows.
The example shows how to provide a height constraint by setting an explicit height for the `DataGrid` (for the first `DataGrid`) and by using the implicit height that is calculated by the parent `Grid` (for the second `DataGrid`).

The first `DataGrid` is located in the second row. The height constraint is locally set by setting `DataGrid.Height`.

The second `DataGrid` is located in the third row, which is set to `*`: it will stretch to occupy the remaining height of the parent (the `Grid`, where `Grid.Height` is dictated by `Window.Height`).
Because the `Height` returned by the third row evaluates to an actual value, the contained `DataGrid.Height` will automatically adapt to this value.

For both `DataGrid` elements, due to the height constraint, the overflowing of rows will result in the scroll bars being displayed.

```xml
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Search Box -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="SP_SearchBox"
              Grid.Row="0" />

    <!-- Auto Suggestion box -->
    <Popup x:Name="Popup" />

    <!-- Grid 1 uses explicit height -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="DG_Orders"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="250" />

    <!-- Grid 2 uses implicit height -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="DG_OrderItems"
              Grid.Row="2" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```